# can't create react-native app with npx react-native init command

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

whenever I try to start a new project with npx react-native init command I get the following error:

```
>     error Error: Command failed: yarn init -y
>     Usage: yarn [options]
>     
>     yarn: error: no such option: -y
```

I have linux mint OS and when I try to create a new react natove app with expo everything works fine., when I try to run same command with sudo but then I got

> sh: 1: react-native: Permission denied

I have linux mint OS and when I try to create a new react native app with expo everything works fine. I have 16.17.1 version of Node and I tried to remove react native CLI and reinstalling it but couldn't sort this problem out. What causes this error and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay seems like I had old version of yarn after updating yarn to the last version I solved the problem.